# Chromecast styled receiver app ID

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am unable to cast with my styled receiver from chrome browser.

I have an unpublished styled receiver chromecast app.  The "preview" button works fine.  My testing device is registered with status "ready for testing".  The send serial number checkbox is checked from my android app (OS X app never finds chromecast, so I cannot verify with another app).

Setting the app ID to be my application ID (which seems to be an 8 digit number in the SDK developer console) throws a session error when I try to connect.  Changing this back to the default app ID has success.  I registered a second identical application and tried with that ID as well.

What could have gone wrong?  I am unable to connect to the debugging console, but I read on SO that you need a custom receiver (not styled receiver) to connect.

I am able to connect to the custom receiver as defined in [this sample receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome/blob/master/CastVideos.js#L145) as well.

Is there no testing for styled receivers?

Note that there is one oddity about my setup, and that is that the chromecast is connecting to a wifi network that has been shared by my macbook, not a normal router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was use a router instead of sharing internet access via Wi-Fi from my macbook. Re-checked the send serial number box, restarted device and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom receiver to be able to debug, using your own Styled receiver is adequate (you basically need to have your own App Id). I would suggest you double check your serial number; take a photo and enlarge that to make sure it was read correctly.

Comment: It is input correctly. I have tried it with two chromecasts, and also tried it with alternate characters (e.g. switching zero to O). I have checked this many times, and had someone else check as well.  Still does not work.

Comment: You can contact https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?rd=1 t get further help on this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find such a contact address but had no luck.